# (Java) I'm getting a logic error when executing my code for a Coin Flip Program

Tags: java

Here is the code I'm given:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabProgram {
   
   /* Define your method here */
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random(2); // Unique seed
      // Add more variables as needed

      /* Type your code here. */
   }
}
```

I cannot make CHANGES to the code, only add things to it. My instructions are:

Write a program that simulates flipping a coin to make decisions. The input is how many decisions are needed, and the output is either heads or tails. Assume the input is a value greater than 0.

Ex: If the input is:

3
the output is:

tails
heads
tails

For reproducibility needed for auto-grading, seed the program with a value of 2. In a real program, you would seed with the current time. In that case, every program's output would be different, which is what is desired but can't be auto-graded.

Note: A common student mistake is to create an instance of Random before each call to rand.nextInt(). But seeding should only be done once, at the start of the program, after which rand.nextInt() can be called any number of times.

Your program must define and call the following method that randomly picks 0 or 1 and returns "heads" or "tails". Assume the value 0 represents "heads" and 1 represents "tails".
public static String headsOrTails(Random rand)

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static String headsOrTails(Random rand) {
      rand.nextInt();
      
      if (rand.equals(0)) {
      return "heads";
      }
      
      else {
      return "tails";
      }
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random(2); // Unique seed
      int userNum = scnr.nextInt();

      for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
         System.out.println(headsOrTails(rand));
      }
   }
}
```

When executing the code, I get tails tail tails, every time.

Comment: ``rand`` is the random number generator. It is not a number. You need something like ``int n = rand.nextInt(2);`` Please look up the documentation on Random.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my method to  `public static String headsOrTails(Random rand) {
      int outcome;
      
      outcome = rand.nextInt();
      
      if (outcome == 0) {
      return "heads";
      }
      
      else {
      return "tails";
      }
   }` And I am still getting "tails tails tails"

Comment: You have to provide an upper bound.

Comment: In case you didn't see my final version, I changed it so that you don't get the same values every time you run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Random package can actually return a random boolean value.  If you pass `2` when you create the Random object, you'll always get the same sequence.  To avoid that, pass in the current Unix time:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class LabProgram {

    public static String headsOrTails(Random rand) {
        boolean r = rand.nextBoolean();
        if (r) {
            return "heads";
        }
        else {
            return "tails";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Unique seed
        int userNum = scnr.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
            System.out.println(headsOrTails(rand));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful to know. For this lab, I had to use a seed, but appreciate seeing how to use the local time as well for a more random experience!

Comment: Gotta love those random experiences, eh? :o)

Comment: Not sure why you are using this Random Constructor.  The javadocs for the no-arg constructor state "Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor." - I think this is suitable for this noob's case.  Using the no-args the result is `10
tails
heads
tails
heads
heads
tails
tails
heads
tails
tails`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Did you actually read the question? His use of the seed of 2 was required by his teacher.

Comment: @NomadMaker Hey I missed this.  But why the tone?  So how does using `System.currentTimeMillis()` equate to `2` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat - That was me.  I missed the "2 is a requirement" thing too, and the system time seed thing is just how I've always done it.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class LabProgram {

```
public static String headsOrTails(Random rand) {
    boolean r = rand.nextBoolean();
    if (r) {
        return "tails";
    }
    else {
        return "heads";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random(2); // Unique seed
    int userNum = scnr.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
        System.out.println(headsOrTails(rand));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class LabProgram{   
public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random(2);
      int flips = scnr.nextInt();

      for(int i=0;i<flips;i++){
         coinFlip(rand);
      }
   }
   
    public static String coinFlip(Random rand){
      if(rand.nextInt(2)+1 == 1){
         System.out.println("Tails");
         return "Tails";
      } else {
         System.out.println("Heads");
         return "Heads" ;
      }
     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static String coinFlip(Random rand){
      int coinFlip = rand.nextInt(2);
      
      if(coinFlip == 0){
         return "Tails";
         }
      else{
         return "Heads";
         }
      
      }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random(2); // Seed used in develop mode
      int numFlips = scnr.nextInt();
      String results;

      for(int i = 0; i < numFlips; ++i){
         results = coinFlip(rand);
         System.out.println(results);
         }
   }
}
```